# Flask SocketIO: Per client settings

Tags: python-3.x, socket.io, flask-socketio

When multiple clients connect to my socketio flask application, how can I achieve per-client settings?

What I have:

```
@socketio.on('replay-start')
def replay(message):
    while True:
        if not paused:
            emit('replay', dict(data=f'private replay'))
        socketio.sleep(1)
```

Now if a client sends a pause event, I want only the clients loop to pause.

If I implement it like this:

```
@socketio.on('replay-pause')
def replay_pause(message):
    global paused
    paused = True
```

Of course this pauses all loops, and not just the one of the current client.
Is there some way to achieve this? Maybe there is some "context object" where I can see the id of the client sending the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most convenient way to store per-client settings is to use the Flask user session, which does work (with certain limitations) on Socket.IO handlers:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session

@socketio.on('replay-start')
def replay(message):
    while True:
        if not session.get('paused'):
            emit('replay', dict(data=f'private replay'))
        socketio.sleep(1)

@socketio.on('replay-pause')
def replay_pause(message):
    session['paused'] = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, there is `request.sid` which is documented [here](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/implementation_notes.html):

> The request context global is enhanced with a sid member that is set to a unique session ID for the connection. This value is used as an initial room where the client is added.

so this would work:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

paused = defaultdict(bool)

@socketio.on('replay-start')
def replay(message):
    while True:
        if not paused[request.sid]:
            emit('replay', dict(data=f'private replay'))
        socketio.sleep(1)

@socketio.on('replay-pause')
def replay_pause(message):
    global paused
    paused[request.sid] = True
```